# JavaFX Check if multiple elements are being hovered

Tags: java, javafx

I have coded an animation which slides out a search bar from my navigation bar when a user clicks on the 'Users' navigation tab.

I want the reverse animation to play if my searchbar loses focus or if the navigation button the user has pressed to to slide the bar out loses focus (as decribed in fig1)[image: image describing my problem]

I currently achieve the effect by setting the onMouseExited property of the search_wrapper to run my `hideUsers()` method, but ideally I want to check

```
nav_button.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
     @Override 
     public void handle(MouseEvent e)
     {
        if(search_wrapper loses focus OR  nav_button loses focus)
           hideUsers();
     }
}
```

How would I go about achieving this? I have tired using the .isFocused() method on both elements but that failed to produce any results.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice GUI you have there..

Comment: Very nice UI ,can you share with us your dashbord ?

Comment: @SoltaniNeji please excuse the code, its kinda bad quality (I wrote this 3 years ago when I was new to programming).  You can find the source here: https://github.com/alexmk92/PRCSE-Desktop-Dashboard/tree/master/src/prcse/pp please bare in mind that I haven't tested it since I compiled it 3 years ago, there may be some compilation errors.  Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `isFocused()` not working?
Anyway, I can suggest you to try using JavaFX's property binding features:

```
// define a boolean property
final BooleanProperty multipleFocusedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

// add listener to track changes in its value, for debugging purpose only here
multipleFocusedProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        System.out.println("newValue multiple focused = " + newValue);
    }
});

// bind it to other property values
multipleFocusedProperty.bind(search_wrapper.focusedProperty().not().or(nav_button.focusedProperty().not()));

// finally use it as
nav_button.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
     if(multipleFocusedProperty.getValue())
         hideUsers();
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why isFocused() was not working but this has solved my problem, thank-you very much Uluk!